# Exporting geo nodes animation of a deforming mesh to glb

Tags: geometry-nodes, baking, animation-nodes, three.js, surface-deform

I have a very specific question about exporting my blender geo nodes animation in a glb file. The issue I face right now is that part of the animation I built is not getting exported. I need it as glb for my three.js project later on.

With "CVS-file-Datapoints" I created points on a position and generated a mesh. The animation is an empty object transforming the z axis and keyframes comes from the frequency of an audiofile. This animation is called up in the object info node. As the z axis moves the object mesh deformes with every keyframe because it reconnectes the points to a new mesh.
I assume one of the problems is in the moment when the mesh is created, because this animation of deforming the mesh is not exported. Also I can not apply the geo nodes modifier without losing the animation.

I tried a few things but am very lost. Exporting to alembic file does work, but as I export it again to glb it looses the animation again.
Creating a simulation zone and baking it was another option I thought of but not sure if I even did it the right way.

I would be soooo very thankfulif somebody can help!
Lene

[image: geo nodes setting data to position]
[image: geo nodes setting creating mesh]
[image: object]
[image: animation movement]

Comment: A _Geometry Nodes_ _Simulation Zone_ is not a keyframed animation, it is a simulation, therefore you cannot export it to *.glb or other formats. A _Geometry Nodes_ modifier is generating geometry. If you apply it, you'll get the geometry it generated. And if this geometry was simulated, you'll get the geometry that exists on that frame on which you apply the modifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response! I can also built the geometry and animation without the simulation zone because I have as well the keyframes for the animation. But do you have any idea how to bake the animation to the object so that I can apply the geo nodes modifier and still have the animation?

Comment: You cannot create an animation inside _Geometry Nodes_ and keep it after applying the modifier. You need an animation outside of _Geometry Nodes_.